# EditText scale with selection

Tags: java, android, editor, pinchzoom, spanned

I have an `EditText` I want to zoom it, and scroll with `setScaleX`/`setScaleY` and it works fine - text is being edited in the right position.

But when I try to select text - it draws selection handles to positions like when text is not scaled. It is known [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57408).

It's expected result because handles are drawn on popup window related to view size.

All actions on `android.widget.Editor` are targeted to its field `private TextView mTextView;`. And if we will set own editor by reflection, I don't know what to do with private methods, that are no overridable.

Also selection handles are drawn on Popup window `android.widget.Editor.HandleView#HandleView` coordinates calculated in Layout and I need only `DynamicLayout` but it have no difference for our purposes.

Method `android.text.Layout#getPrimaryHorizontal(int, boolean)` is public and its value can be multiplied on scale, but for that we need to extend and override private method `android.widget.TextView#makeSingleLayout`, but this is a problem.

Also we could implement our own Layout with all required overriden methods, but all methods that we can override are marked with `@hide` annotation and there are no fields that can be accessed with a reflection.

Next screenshot appears for scaled on 2x

[image]

PS: context of the task is an Editor with pinch-to-zoom edit text. Relayout of text with calculation of size is not a solution. Because I need Portable Document on each screen size.

Comment: Please consider formatting that wall of text. It's not too easy to read.

Comment: Sorry, @Avanz. Right now i can't accept your solution, because can't approve not checked solution. as for me a lot of spans has metric affection. Also i have a lot custom spans, so in this solution i should override each one to return scaled size. i have 22 custom span, character and paragraph ones. Firstly, I will try your solution, then solution will accepted.

Comment: All right. Have your time and give it a go. Anything just let me know.

Comment: This functionality moved to second release. actual dates is August.

Answer (score 13):

You can do that using [MetricAffectingSpan](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/text/style/MetricAffectingSpan.java). Here is a class exemplifying it:

```
package android.text.style;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.text.ParcelableSpan;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.text.TextUtils;

public class AbsoluteSizeSpan extends MetricAffectingSpan implements ParcelableSpan {

    private final int mSize;
    private boolean mDip;

    /**
     * Set the text size to <code>size physical pixels.
     */
    public AbsoluteSizeSpan(int size) {
        mSize = size;
    }

    /**
     * Set the text size to <code>size physical pixels,
     * or to <code>size device-independent pixels if
     * <code>dip is true.
     */
    public AbsoluteSizeSpan(int size, boolean dip) {
        mSize = size;
        mDip = dip;
    }

    public AbsoluteSizeSpan(Parcel src) {
        mSize = src.readInt();
        mDip = src.readInt() != 0;
    }

    public int getSpanTypeId() {
        return TextUtils.ABSOLUTE_SIZE_SPAN;
    }

    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(mSize);
        dest.writeInt(mDip ? 1 : 0);
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return mSize;
    }

    public boolean getDip() {
        return mDip;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        if (mDip) {
            ds.setTextSize(mSize * ds.density);
        } else {
            ds.setTextSize(mSize);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint ds) {
        if (mDip) {
            ds.setTextSize(mSize * ds.density);
        } else {
            ds.setTextSize(mSize);
        }
    }
}
```

Reference: [Java Source Code Warehouse project](http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/text/style/AbsoluteSizeSpan.java.shtml)

You need to play with [MetricAffectingSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/MetricAffectingSpan.html) and [wrap(CharacterStyle cs)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/CharacterStyle.html) - which allows *CharacterStyle* to be applied to a single region of a given Spanned.

In your subclass, override *onTouch* and pass its values to a *ScaleGestureDetector*. Store the detected scale as a member variable.

Override *onDraw*, and call [canvas.scale()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21546762/how-to-pinch-zoom-an-edittext-in-android) with your scale value prior to calling through to *super.onDraw*. As you can notice in the *AbsoluteSizeSpan*, using *AbsoluteSizeSpan(Parcel src)* will get the text you wish to resize, then you apply *updateDrawState*.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about how this fixes the issue with the handles not rendering at the correct size?

Comment: Really i have no time to try sollution. But I'll return to it soon. Anybody have checked it, please comment. Avanz, thank you for fullest answer.

Comment: /** @hide */
    public static final int ABSOLUTE_SIZE_SPAN = 16;

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to apply different styles to these elements? I think it should work with some conditioning.

```
<item name="android:textSelectHandle">@drawable/text_select_handle_middle</item>
<item name="android:textSelectHandleLeft">@drawable/text_select_handle_left</item>
<item name="android:textSelectHandleRight">@drawable/text_select_handle_right</item>
```

Comment: Can you explain how you think that would solve the improper re-sizig issue?

Comment: Thing is that the bug you're dealing with isn't "solvable" by any standard approach I know of. And you've probably already tried some non-standard approaches. What I'm trying to propose is setting the style for the selection and changing drawables dynamically, scaling (edit: and positioning) them in the process. Note that I haven't tried to attempt that, maybe tommorow I'll fiddle around with it as GMT is killing me.

Comment: Ah, so you think if the styles are changed after the resize is done, the handles might resize appropriately?

Comment: It's only a thought, worth trying I guess.